# Using objects in method arguments

Tags: java, object

I am working on a lab and it is asking me to create a method and test it. The method I created uses an object as one of the arguments. When testing the method what would I put in the argument that asks for an object. I apologize if this is confusing I will try to post enough so someone can help. Let me know if you need more information.

Here is the method I was told to create. The object I am talking about is the first argument in buildRow(). I am trying to test that method but do not know what to put as the first argument. The HtmlFormat is just another class I made and used but shouldn't really matter for my question.

[image]

Here is how I am trying to test it. The WhoDataItem is also another class that I am using to grab other method from.

[image]

Here is the WhoDataItem class if you need to look at it. I am just using the getCountry() method.

[image]

Comment: Obviously, an instance of `WhoDataItem`. Also, please post code as code, not as images.

Comment: Please paste code/errors as text. I expect that you will put in as much effort as you expect of the volunteers who answer you.